# how do I move around java gui elements?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, design-patterns

```
    Panel controlPanel = new Panel ();
    JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttomsPanel = new JPanel();

    controlPanel = new Panel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(10));



    Panel panel = new Panel();

    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    panel.setSize(700,700);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(6,6, 10, 10);

    panel.setLayout(layout);


    for (int i= 0; i < 36; i++){
         panel.add(new Button(""));
    }
    controlPanel.add(panel);


    buttomsPanel.add(new Button(""));
    frame.add(buttomsPanel);


    frame.add(controlPanel);
    frame.setSize(900, 700);
```

Basically the second button that I add to the gui won't be displayed. Also, I want to put another two fields and I do not know how to move them either, or whether they should go into a panel first and then be moved.

Comment: `Button` is either a JavaFX or a AWT component. AWT components may not play nice within a Swing container (like `JPanel`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the ambaguity...

`Button` is either a `java.awt.Button` or a `javafx.scene.control.Button`, in either case, it's probably not going to play well with a `JPanel`.

`Panel` is a `java.awt.Panel` and won't play well with Swing.  It's just easier to not mix AWT components within Swing.

Next, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, this means when you do something like...

```
frame.add(buttomsPanel);
frame.add(controlPanel);
```

It's the `controlPanel` which is likely to be the one which is displayed (and given the oddities of z-ordering between AWT and Swing, it's likely to want to be displayed regardless of the order you add them).

To fix this, you need to specify the position within the `BorderLayout` where you want the panels added, for example...

```
frame.add(buttomsPanel);
frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

And use a `JPanel` instead of a `Panel` and `JButton`s instead of `Button`...

See [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)  for details

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(10));
                JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel();
                JPanel buttomsPanel = new JPanel();

                Panel panel = new Panel();

                panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                panel.setSize(700, 700);
                GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(6, 6, 10, 10);

                panel.setLayout(layout);

                for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
                    panel.add(new JButton(""));
                }
                controlPanel.add(panel);

                buttomsPanel.add(new JButton(""));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(buttomsPanel);
                frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```